# Is the Unit ball of $X^{**} $ weak*- sequentially compact?

Tags: banach-spaces, schauder-basis, weak-topology, reflexive-space

Am in the middle of a problem and i have the following conditions :

> Let $X$ be a reflexive Banach space with Schauder basis $(e_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$, i have a sequence $x_n^{**} \in B_{X^{**}}\biggl(0,1\biggr)$ where $B_{X^{**}}\biggl(0,1\biggr)=\{x^{**} \in X^{**} : \lVert{x^{**}}\rVert \leq 1\}$.

And i wanna know if $(x_n^{**})$ has a limit point in the weak$^*$-topology of $X^{**}$ in other words if the unit ball with the weak$^*$-topology is sequentially compact.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The [Eberlein-Smulian Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eberlein%E2%80%93%C5%A0mulian_theorem) may be relevant, along with Banach-Alaoglu.

Comment: @GEdgar ...The space is reflexive.

Comment: @RhysSteele Maybe you mean that since is reflexive weak concides with the weak$^*$ of $X^{**}$?

Comment: @dem0nakos Yes, that's precisely why I suggested Eberlein-Smulian.

Comment: OK, with reflexive it is of course true...